# Find out if a process is legitimately allowed to use "shared memory segments"

Tags: memory, rootkits

`rkhunter` is checking for processes using shared memory segments and warns with output like:

```
Warning: The following suspicious (large) shared memory segments have been found: Process: /usr/bin/python3.7 Size: 4,0MB (configured size allowed: 1,0MB)
```

Those warnings can be disabled in the `rkhunter` config with the option `ALLOWIPCPROC=path/to/service` but it is not wise to just disable all warnings without checking if the process is not suspicious.

How do I find out if it is normal that a process (like `/usr/bin/python3.7`) is using large shared memories?

Comment: A lot of things use large shared memory segments. That's pretty normal. Also, I have to say that rkhunter is not a very good rootkit detection tool. It's really only useful on very old systems that may be infected with old and well-known rootkits.

Comment: so which detection tool do you suggest? Should `rkhunter` dev team ommit those checks then?

Comment: What kind of rootkits are you trying to detect? For basic userspace rootkits, AIDE is pretty good, given that it's a powerful integrity checker (with the checking being done offline on another system, typically), but there are no heuristic-based rootkit detection tools that are even remotely difficult to fool.

Comment: I configured aide and try to use it instead of rkhunter now: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074558/installing-aide-on-ubuntu-18-04-1/1184314#1184314 unfortunately `aide` only uses one CPU which takes ages!

Comment: It's not a very fast utility, and it's meant to be run _offline_ (i.e. on another, known-good computer). You can get realtime integrity protection on Linux with IMA (Integrity Measurement Architecture), which creates a hash tree of files and utilizes a TPM to protect the root hash. Note that it can reduce performance because it breaks demand paging.

Comment: is `chkrootkit` a better tool?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100353/discussion-between-forest-and-rubo77).